# angular aot build showing type of undefined errors in node_module typescript.js

Tags: angular, typescript, node-modules, angular2-aot, ng-build

when i run ng build command with prod=true and aot=true these errors show up.

> ERROR in : TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
> at Object.getEffectiveTypeAnnotationNode (/Users/zawhtetaung/Documents/Brainlitz-Web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:9432:18)
> at assignContextualParameterTypes (/Users/zawhtetaung/Documents/Brainlitz-Web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:37839:25)
> at checkFunctionExpressionOrObjectLiteralMethod (/Users/zawhtetaung/Documents/Brainlitz-Web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:38136:29)
> at checkExpressionWorker (/Users/zawhtetaung/Documents/Brainlitz-Web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:39148:28)
> at checkExpression (/Users/zawhtetaung/Documents/Brainlitz-Web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:39077:42)
> at checkBinaryLikeExpression (/Users/zawhtetaung/Documents/Brainlitz-Web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:38657:29)
> at checkBinaryExpression (/Users/zawhtetaung/Documents/Brainlitz-Web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:38649:20)
> at checkExpressionWorker (/Users/zawhtetaung/Documents/Brainlitz-Web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:39169:28)
> at checkExpression (/Users/zawhtetaung/Documents/Brainlitz-Web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:39077:42)
> at checkBinaryLikeExpression (/Users/zawhtetaung/Documents/Brainlitz-Web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:38657:29)
> at checkBinaryExpression (/Users/zawhtetaung/Documents/Brainlitz-Web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:38649:20)
> at checkExpressionWorker (/Users/zawhtetaung/Documents/Brainlitz-Web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:39169:28)
> at checkExpression (/Users/zawhtetaung/Documents/Brainlitz-Web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:39077:42)
> at checkExpressionStatement (/Users/zawhtetaung/Documents/Brainlitz-Web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:41199:13)
> at checkSourceElement (/Users/zawhtetaung/Documents/Brainlitz-Web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:43009:28)
> at Object.forEach (/Users/zawhtetaung/Documents/Brainlitz-Web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:1500:30)

this is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"]
  }
}
```

and this is my package.json dependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.112",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "husky": "^2.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lint-staged": "^8.2.1",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
```

I don't know where to start as I have never faced errors in node_modules but I'm thinking maybe it's version mismatched perhaps? I've already googled quite enough and couldn't find anything i can use of. So just any idea would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Aight since no one answered, i just upgraded typescript version to 2.6.2 and it was fine. So it was version mismatch problem.